# Raster Multiplication - Can't Multiply Sequence by Non-Int of Type "Float"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, map-algebra, floating-point

I am trying to multiply a list of GRID raster datasets using a different value for each raster. The value is in the raster name. Some examples are [wse_1979_5,wse_1980_0,wse_1980_5], where 1979_5, 1980_0, and 1980_5 will become 1979.5, 1980.0, and 1980.5. Every raster currently is classified where VALUE = 1 for all cells, and multiplying by the above values from the names should make the raster datasets equal to those values. So far I have:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = *path*
from arcpy.sa import *
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in rasters:
    multValue = float(raster[4:-2]+"."+raster[-1])
    outRaster = raster * multValue
    outRaster.save(raster+"_r")
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I am getting "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'". I believe I need to somehow iterate the raster since it is apparently a string(?), but I'm not positive and can't quite figure this one out. It is simple to do in raster calculator, but I have a lot of datasets to multiply.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arcpy.ListRasters()` is returning a list of raster filenames not Raster objects. In your loop you're trying to multiply a string (the raster filename) by the float value which causes the `TypeError` exception. You need to multiply a *Raster object* by the float value. Convert your file name to a Raster object using [arcpy.sa.Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000)

```
from arcpy.sa import *

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in rasters:
    multValue = float(raster[4:-2]+"."+raster[-1])
    outRaster = Raster(raster) * multValue  # < ---------- Raster object * float value
    outRaster.save(raster+"_r")
```